# Strict Standard PHP ERROR CAKE

Tags: php, cakephp, strict

I am gettig errors on this penny auction script i purchased a while back from a company which is now defunct, their website is offline and there is no way to get tech support from them this worked in the past about a year to two years ago, now that it is uploaded i am getting TONS of errors. Can anyone help?

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/config/core.php on line 50
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 373
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/config/core.php on line 51
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 373
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 643
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 373
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 663
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 664
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 373
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 670
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 671
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 373
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::config() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 676
Strict Standards: Non-static method Cache::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 99
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::read() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/cache.php on line 373
Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/elevenbravo1990/public_html/TEST/cake/libs/configure.php on line 327
```

Comment: are you using cakephp 1.3 ?

Comment: If that is the same penny auction script I've had recently on my desk, good luck, you've bought a huge pile of fail, the code is horrible bad and insecure as well.

Answer (score 8):

If your cakephp version is 1.3 and php5.4

In php 5.4, `E_STRICT` comes under `E_ALL`

`/cake/bootstrap.php` replace `error_reporting()` with this one ...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

ref : https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=665218

Answer (score 0):

As Rajeev suggested but error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED) should be at cake\cake\libs\configure.php in my case